# How to get parents of an element with xpath in selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have a script that takes all the images I want on a webpage, then I have to take the link that enclose the `image`.

I actually click on every image, take the current page link and then I go back and continue with the work. This is slow but I have an `a` tag that "hug" my `image`, I don't know how to retrieve that tag. With the tag it could be easier and faster. I attach the html code and my python code!

**HTML code**

```
<div class="col-xl col-lg col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
<a href="URL I WANT TO GET ">
<article>
<span class="year">2017</span>
<span class="quality">4K</span>
<span class="imdb">6.7</span>
<img width="190" height="279" src="THE IMAGE URL" class="img-full wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy"> <h2>TITLE</h2>
</article>
</a></div>
<div class="col-xl col-lg col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
<a href="URL I WANT TO GET 2">
<article>
<span class="year">2019</span>
<span class="quality">4K</span>
<span class="imdb">8.0</span>
<img width="190" height="279" src="THE IMAGE URL 2" class="img-full wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy"> <h2>TITLE</h2>
</article>
</a></div>
```

**Python code**

```
self.driver.get(category_url)
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.archivePaging')))  # a div to see if page is loaded
movies_buttons = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('img.img-full.wp-post-image')

print("Getting all the links!")
for movie in movies_buttons:
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", movie)
    movie.click()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'infoFilmSingle')))
    print(self.driver.current_url)
    self.driver.back()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.archivePaging')))
```

Note that this code don't work now because i'm calling a movie object of an old page but that's not a problem because if i would just see the link i don't need to change page and so the session don't change.

Comment: there is <div class="col-xl col-lg col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6"> before the first a in the html code. sorry i'm new here and i don't know if i can edit the answer

Comment: im quite sure that this is not gonna work since the driver.find_element will only find one element, and the "s" after element[s] doesnt exist. You might need to use another library to scrape all the hrefs, and then manually insert it into a "driver.get()" function

Comment: Whats the issue your a facing its hard to understand

Comment: @Timeler There is a "s" existing to get multiple elements [Selenium - Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: @HedgeHog Didnt know that, thanks a lot

Comment: what error are you getting? Stale element reference? That is because you're clicking & going back (which causes the DOM to refresh). you need to click into new windows, or save the URLS and access them individually (not through clicks)

Comment: @Rom7x Is the _href_ attribute `URL I WANT TO GET ` and _src_ attribute `THE IMAGE URL` different? Seems you want to make a _list_, which one would you like to extract?

Answer (score 1):

An example based on what I understand you want to do - You wanna get the parent `a` tags `href`

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

html_content = """
<div class="col-xl col-lg col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
    <a href="https://www.link1.de">
        <article>
            <span class="year">2017</span>
            <span class="quality">4K</span>
            <span class="imdb">6.7</span>
            <img width="190" height="279" src="THE IMAGE URL" class="img-full wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy"> <h2>TITLE</h2>
        </article>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xl col-lg col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
    <a href="https://www.link2.de">
        <article>
            <span class="year">2019</span>
            <span class="quality">4K</span>
            <span class="imdb">8.0</span>
            <img width="190" height="279" src="THE IMAGE URL 2" class="img-full wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy"> <h2>TITLE</h2>
        </article>
    </a>
</div>
"""
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))
```

Locate the `image elements` with its `class` and and walk up the element structur with `..` in this case `/../..`

```
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))
aTags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@class,'img-full wp-post-image')]/../..")
for ele in aTags:
  x=ele.get_attribute('href')
  print(x)
driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
https://www.link1.de/
https://www.link2.de/
```

Comment: Was it that simple? Thank you very much, I will study how xpath works as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: Is it there also a selenium function to do that? I mean, it's good I can do this with xpath but what if we could do also with selenium something like this: object.parent().parent() to get the <a> tag

Comment: @Rom7x Not sure, that is what the docs tell us - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html 

If you would provide an `url` or more `dom` it could be possible that you do not have to find the parents rather walk top down in the tree.

Comment: thanks, it isn't saying nothing so i assume that i have to do as you described with xpath.